# two sessions creating in rails devise with apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, devise, apartment-gem

I am using [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem for multi tenant and devise gem for authentication every thing looks good and working fine but sometimes problem occurs when I login then devise did not take me to backend and redirect to home page.

Then I noticed in browser cookies that two session is created in local storage just like that

**1**:
name: _newss_demo_store_session
value: blablaa
domain: .www.lvh.me

**2**:
name: _newss_demo_store_session
value: blabla
domain: .lvh.me

And when I removed these cookies from browser then devise login take me to backend and everything start working. I did not found any solution please help or suggest any solution or If I did anything wrong.

Thanks

Comment: can you paste your config.session_store ?

Comment: @JackBites, Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_newss_demo_store_session', domain: :all

Comment: have you tried with tld_length: 2 ?

Comment: Not yet let me try that. Thanks :)

Comment: Devise takes authentication from warden session, have you followed instruction well? like adding Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 'Warden::Manager', 'Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain' or this url https://github.com/influitive/apartment#middleware-considerations

Comment: Yes I have added that 'Warden' middleware :)